# tabwidget в новом активити

Tags: java, android

Использую TabWidget, состоящий из 5 элементов (каждый это отдельное активити).

```
tabHost.addTab(tabNews);
tabHost.addTab(tabServices);
tabHost.addTab(tabContacts);
tabHost.addTab(tabEvakautor);
tabHost.addTab(tabProfile);
```

Переключаясь между табами виджет пристуствует (внизу экрана), но если запустить новое активити, данный TabWidget на него не переходит. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при переключении на новое активити(которое не определено в tabhost), виджет так же отображался на этом активити? Прошу подсказать, где можно почитать или просмотреть пример реализации.

Comment: Вы наверно и перфокартами еще пользуетесь? Или может телевизор ламповый вместо монитора? Я бы рекомендовал вам перейти на что-нибудь более современное, например фрагменты.

Comment: @metalurgus насколько я знаю, вкладки через Fragment нельзя сделать снизу экрана.

Comment: Плохо вы знаете. Как насчет погуглить? https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=android+fragments+tabs+bottom&oq=android+fragments+tabs+bottom&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3j69i64.8630j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: целый день гуглю, ничего не нашел, поэтому решил спросить на форуме - а тут обратно в гугл, замкнутый круг.

Comment: уж утрудитесь, я в первой или второй ссылке нашел ответ

Comment: короче, `FragmentTabHost`

Comment: C FragmentTabHost разобрался, спасибо! Может кто и на вопрос даст ответ, поглядим!